# Example of a Symbol: Connection.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm trying to get more intuition for the symbol of a differential operator. In particular, I've tried the example of a connection. What is the most efficient way to compute the symbol for, say, a linear connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E\to X$, given locally by
$$\nabla s^{\alpha} =\sum_\beta(\partial_\beta-A_\beta) s^\alpha?$$